# Get all records between two dates

Tags: codeigniter

How can i fetch all records between two date field dates in mysql table.Am using code igniter for my application.

Am entering start date and end date from date picker , need to fetch all rowas >= startdate and <= end date

my code:-

```
 $this->db->where('start_date <= ',$start_date);
 $this->db->where('end_date >= ',$end_date);
```

My query :-  SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `start_date` <= '2016-04-13' AND `end_date` >= '2016-04-19'

This is fetching only one row from table.

Please help

Comment: Update your question with the result of `echo $this->db->last_query();` after executing the query mentioned in your post.

Comment: I have updated the question with query thanks.

Comment: Check whether `SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date <= '2016-04-13';` and `SELECT * FROM table WHERE end_date >= '2016-04-13';` are working or not.

Comment: my query is working but not matching all the records there are other records withing the dates but query is fetching specified row only

Comment: Did you try the queries mentioned in my previous comment? Are they working as expected?

Comment: yes , your queries  are working.

Comment: Then verify your data and sql conditions again.

Comment: all correct actually if my query is like SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date <= '2016-04-1' AND end_date >= '2016-05-30' i will get this particular row only, i will not get row with 2016-04-5 to 2016-5-1.This is my issue

Comment: It is working now.Thanks for all help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U need to do something like this...

```
 $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%d/%Y') as Urdate",FALSE);
 $this->db->from('table');
 $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') > '2013-01-01'",NULL,FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this one:

```
$this->db->where('start_date >= ',$start_date);
$this->db->where('end_date <= ',$end_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('manual_discount');
    $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(created_datetime,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2018-09-06'",NULL,FALSE);
    $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(created_datetime,'%Y-%m-%d') <= '2018-09-06'",NULL,FALSE);
```

this works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

To solve the above issue you should following below query.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');

$this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where('start_date <=',$start_date);
    $this->db->where('end_date >=',$start_date);
$this->db->group_end();

$this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where('start_date <=',$end_date);
    $this->db->where('end_date >=',$end_date);
$this->db->group_end();
```