# MySQL Find if 2 dates are between in date ranges for multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, date

I am using Codeigniter + MySQL + Active Record and i am building a project with time periods for room prices.

I have the below schema in my mysql table

> Package_periods

[image]

> Room_package_prices

[image]

A `package_id` can have many periods as you can see in the example `01-08-17 to 08-08-2017`, `10-08-2017 to 17-08-2017` etc.

For a given searched period (let's say `02-08-2017 to 14-08-2017`), how can i find the `package_id` that not only exceeds the searched period but also there is not even 1 day outside of the searched period?

I mean, the `package_id` periods (from and to through multiple mysql rows), should cover ALL the days of a searched period without leaving a single gap.

```
public function getFHotels($checkin = null, $checkout = null, $adults = null, $packageType = null, $package_id = null, $limit, $start, $lang_id) {
        $this->db->select('DISTINCT(hotels.hotel_id)')
                ->from('hotels')
                ->join('rooms', 'rooms.hotel_id=hotels.hotel_id')
                ->where('rooms.room_active', 1)
                ->where('hotels.hotel_active', 1)
                ->limit($limit, $start);

        if ($packageType) {
            $this->db->where('rooms.room_package_id', $packageType);
        }
        if ($package_id && $adults) {
            //if $package_id is given, do not search for checkin-checkout
            $this->db->join('room_package_prices', 'room_package_prices.room_id=rooms.room_id');
            $this->db->where('room_package_prices.package_period_id', $package_id);
            $this->db->where('room_package_prices.adults', $adults);
            $this->db->where('room_package_prices.price>', 0);
        } elseif ($checkin && $checkout && $adults) {
            //if $checkin and $checkout is given, search for the period_from and period_to
            //Here goes my actual question
        }

        $qry = $this->db->get();
        if ($qry->num_rows() > 0)
            return $qry->result_array();
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? You haven't shared any code with us

Comment: Where's your query?

Comment: Hmmmm haven't tried anything yet, because i don't even know how to query that, but let me edit in a few minutes to add a simple model function :)

Comment: You might find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875668/codeigniter-getting-data-posted-in-between-two-dates

Comment: Added the 2 tables that must participate in the query and my already written function with some comments to help you.

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102195/how-to-query-with-active-record-in-codeigniter-for-dates-between-specified-times

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589385/get-all-records-between-two-dates

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574777/codeigniter-getting-data-between-two-dates-in-mysql-using-php

Comment: I suppose you did a search before asking your question? Or actually I suppose you didn't

Comment: My problem is that a given searched period can be satisfied by many rows. I mean that 3 rows can cover a whole month (01-08 to 10-08 and 11-08 to 20-08 and 21-08 to 31-08). These periods are in different mysql rows so the query will return false. Also all the searched timeline should be in my period_from and period_to and not a single day outside of it.

Comment: I don't think there's going to be any way to do this in a single query. The problem is that each of your records can span an arbitrary date range, and the only way to cycle through them to ensure that there are no "gaps" is to manually do it with your application (PHP). I'm saying this based on a very similar project in which I had to find gaps in a series of dates and it actually involved some tricky date manipulation in PHP, combined with a simple ``SELECT`` of the records.

Comment: Can you share some of you code that could solve my problem? I of my thoughts is that i could loop and query 1 by 1 day through the searched period and find the period that will satisfy all the looped days.

Comment: I have a few questions. #1 In your example, if I search for period from 2017-08-20 to 2017-09-09, it show result package_id = 3, am i right? #2 And if I search from 2017-08-20 to 2017-09-10, (instead of 09-09 in prev search), will it result the same or it violate because it creates 'gaps' which is in 2017-09-10? #3 is package period 4 and 5 considered overlap? if not, when i search from 2017-08-20 to 2017-08-30 will it considered as outside search period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i managed to solve this by myself in a different way. I wanted to implement this functionality in my model function `getFHotels` but couldn't find a way to do that.

So i separated this functionality in my controller and created a new model function just for this purpose. Long story short, the idea was

1. Grab the desired searched period (checkin - checkout) from the client
2. Loop through each day from checkin to checkout and query for every day to the table, which package_id covers that day
3. Push the everyday results in array
4. Find the intersects of the array. If a package_id is in every key of the array, i have found it.

Here is the code:

```
        $begin = new DateTime($checkin);
        $end = new DateTime($checkout);
        $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
        $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
        $legit_packages = array();

        //loop through each day and ask the table if a package_id includes this day
        foreach ($period as $dt) {
            //add each day results in legit_day_packages array
            $legit_day_packages = array();
            $day = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
            //find the packages that include the day
            $periods_found = $this->hotel_model->findFPackagePeriodsPerDay($day);
            if ($periods_found) {
                //foreach found packages, array push in legit_day_packages the results
                foreach ($periods_found as $p_f_key => $p_f) {
                    array_push($legit_day_packages, $p_f['package_id']);
                }
            }
            //Push the legit_day_packages into $legit_packages array. This array will have 1 key per day, containing the package_ids, if found
            array_push($legit_packages, $legit_day_packages);
        }

        //Find the intersect package_id. In this was i exclude the 'gaps'. A package_id must appear in every key per day.
        $first = $legit_packages[0];
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($legit_packages); $i++) {
            $result = array_intersect($first, $legit_packages[$i]);
            $first = $result;
        }

        //the $result contains all the package_id that satisfies both the range and no 'gap' in the period.
        var_dump($result);
```

> Model Function

```
public function findFPackagePeriodsPerDay($day) {
        $qry = $this->db->select('packages.package_id')
                ->from('package_periods')
                ->join('packages', 'packages.package_id=package_periods.package_id')
                ->where('packages.is_package_type', 1)
                ->where('package_periods.period_from<=', $day)
                ->where('package_periods.period_to>=', $day)
                ->get();
        if ($qry->num_rows() > 0)
            return $qry->result_array();
        return FALSE;
    }
```